# Users that haven't installed the font on machine can't see it on the website

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have this fancy website I am working on:
https://omnitored.000webhostapp.com/
The problem is that only people who have the font installed on their machine can see it on the website, otherwise it shows up as Arial.

This is how it looks for me as I have the font installed:
[image: This is how it looks for me as I have the font installed]

And this is how it looks for those who don't have the font installed:

[image]

Also, my css code that stands for the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: infierno;
    src: url(../fonts/infierno.ttf),
    url(../fonts/infierno.eot),
    url(../fonts/infierno.woff);
}
```

I am sure all the names and links in the file are correct, as it works for me both on the host and on local files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` is misspelled in your CSS code. Also, where is the font file located with respect to the CSS file? If the `fonts` folder is located in your root directory, you will need to change the `src` property to go up one folder before going into the `fonts` folder.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: infierno;
    src: url('../fonts/infierno.ttf');
}
```

EDIT: I got it to work using this `@font-face` declaration in Google Chrome. Let me know if this works for you too.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: infernio;
    src: url(../fonts/infierno.ttf),
      url(../fonts/infierno.woff),
      url(../fonts/infierno.eot);  
}
```

Comment: Fixed it like you said: '@font-face {
 font-family: infierno;
 src: url(../fonts/infierno.ttf)
}'

Comment: Still doesn't seem to make effect on the site

Comment: Try a force refresh; also, confirm that the font exists in `fonts/infierno.ttf`, and make sure the font loads correctly (open it on your computer, should prompt you to install it but you don't need to). Are you also applying the `font-family` property to the correct CSS elements you want to have it?

Comment: Check the edit I made; based off of Saeid's answer, but you need to chain multiple font sources in the same `src` property instead of in their own `src` values, or they override each other and cause incompatibility based on the font type (TTF, WOFF, EOF, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Add bellow `.eot` and `.wof` fonts also neer `.ttf`.
and make sure your fonts have been loaded inside your browser by checking your dev console.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'infierno';
    src: url('../fonts/infierno.ttf');
    src: url('../fonts/infierno.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/infierno.wof');
}
```